# How to enable enter key action to be performed after entering data in search box in selenium using python

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide, selenium-grid

HI I am doing some automation script for the website https://silkdb.bioinfotoolkits.net in selenium using python language in which one has to enter a value and click on search that fetches some protein data

[image: Picture]
I have enetered the following code

```
driver.get("https://silkdb.bioinfotoolkits.net")
elements= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='root']/section/ul/li/div/div[2]/span/span[1]/span[1]/span/input")
value="BMSK0011954"

elements.send_keys(value)
elements.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

The value is entered in search box But the enter button action is not being performed Please help in this

Comment: Please tightly couple Keys.Enter with sendkeys method
elements.send_keys(value,Key.Enter)

Comment: There is nothing wrong in your code. same code working fine at my end. How frequently its not working ? all time or some time ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Sending Enter Key value, the value can be selected from the list. Here is a sample code,

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver.get("https://silkdb.bioinfotoolkits.net")
elements= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='root']/section/ul/li/div/div[2]/span/span[1]/span[1]/span/input")
value="BMSK0011954"

elements.send_keys(value)
SearchResult = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH,"//ul/li//span[contains(text(),'"+value+"')]"))
SearchResult.click()
```